# Specifying Permissions on AppDomain Creation in C# using Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm creating a plugin system using C# in .Net 4.5, running on a linux box through Mono 4.2.1. Part of the plugin system requires using separate AppDomains for each plugin to allow dynamic permissions and modification of the plugins. However, I'm unable to create an AppDomain with any PermissionSet other than FullTrust, which defeats the whole purpose of using the AppDomains. On my Windows machine the permissions work fine, which is adding to the confusion. Here's how I'm creating the AppDomain:

```
PermissionSet ps1 = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
ps1.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
AppDomainSetup ads1 = new AppDomainSetup();
ads1.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase;
AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("path/to/plugin/here", null, ads1, ps1, null);
```

Seems simple enough. If I run that on Windows, I get an AppDomain returned with only Execution permission. However, running that through Mono gives me an AppDomain with full trust permissions. I've looked at the [Mono source code for AppDomains](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs) and can't seem to figure out where the permissions are going wrong.

I've also tried reflecting into the newly created AppDomain to change the '_granted' field, which should change future calls to dom.PermissionSet, but that still seems unaffected.

Anyone have insight into what's going wrong and why?